# Windows: How to change monitor's backlight brightness

Tags: windows, monitor, brightness, backlight

Ever since I've been using an external monitor with my laptop, when I need to change the backlight brightness I have to press the monitor's buttons to navigate through its menu and adjust the brightness.
That is really a pain. It's too many button presses! When I was using my laptop's integrated monitor, that was as simple as presing the `Fn` key plus a combination.

Probably some of you might think it is not possible to change that programmatically. I thought that too. But I've just found a control (a GUI control) in my video card configuration that does exactly that.
So, that proves it is possible to change this programmatically.

But I can't find any tool or utility that does that. All what I've found are tools that adjust gamma, brightness and contrast. But backlight brightness is a different thing.

Does any of you know how to adjust that damn thing programmatically in Windows?

Comment: You probably want to ask this on SuperUser.com--other than asking about adjusting brightness via code, this is basically a SuperUser sort of question.

Comment: This is a question that is very specific to you monitor.  For example, I know for a fact that my monitor has no such function.  You would be better off asking on superuser.com for a utility that did such a thing.

Comment: It can't be specific to my monitor. It must be some standard feature, which might be available on some monitors or not, but it definately is a standard feature, otherwise I couldn't be able to adjust my EXTERNAL monitor's backlight with software (video card driver) made for my laptop's integrated monitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try that again.  There is a [SetMonitorBrightness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692972.aspx) function, but it is only available starting with Vista.  There is also [IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372704.aspx) which is available starting with XP SP1.  I might give that a try on my laptop just out of curiosity.

Comment: D'oh; I only skimmed your question.  I am not aware of a standard method to change the backlight.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is about Windows, but if anyone is looking for the Linux way to do this you can run the "xbacklight" program, for example: "xbacklight -set 100" to set to 100% (full) brightness.  The source code to this program could be used to embed it into a program.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tools that let you set the backlight brightness:

- [ScreenBright](http://www.screenwhite.com/screenbright/)
- [Display Tuner](http://www.nicomsoft.com/products/display-tuner/)

The latter uses a custom library which they offer commercially and supports most popular programming languages in Windows. http://www.nicomsoft.com/products/i2c/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an NVidia card with the control panel installed, you should have a brightness control on the `Adjust desktop color settings` node.